# Как правильно говорить: он прочёл или прочитал поэму? Или он рассказал поэму Руслан и Людмила?

Tags: выбор-слов

Прочесть или прочитать поэму со сцены

Answer (score 1):

*Оба* варианта "чтения" возможны, различия только стилистические. Рассказать же можно *содержание поэмы*, историю, сказку. Какой из двух вариантов предпочесть? По моим субъективным ощущениям, вариант "прочёл" акцентирует *краткость* материала, факт завершённости или даже относительную давность действия (возможно, краткость слова влияет на такое восприятие), поэтому в сочетании с *поэмой* (чтение ассоциируется с *продолжительным*, хотя и завершённым действием; в другом контексте "прочитать" может означать "*провести время* за чтением") я бы выбрал **прочитал**. Есть и общее выражение для "прочтения *со сцены*" (это слово зачастую можно опустить): **продекламировал**.